# Get the id of all the checkbox which is altered from the default setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have the following `html` :

```
<table id="share">                          
        <tr class="row">
                <td class="optionsCell">Share Clip postings : </td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="shareClipPost" /><span>Yes</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
                <td class="optionsCell">Share my favorites : </td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="shareFavorites" /><span>Yes</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
                <td class="optionsCell">Share all ratings given/changed : </td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="shareRating" /><span>Yes</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
                <td class="optionsCell">Share all shows recorded : </td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="shareRecorded" /><span>Yes</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
                <td class="optionsCell">Share all shows viewed : </td>
                <td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="shareView"/><span>Yes</span></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Now what i want to achieve is a suitable way so that i can get which checkbox is checked or unchecked. Initially i mark checked for checkboxes from the data got by `ajax` request and rest other boxes remains unchecked. This is in my settings. So now i need to find a way to get the value of only those checkboxes which the user changes may be uncheck the previously checked checkbox or check any unchecked box. Then i can only pass `id`  of the checkboxes which is changed. Now i pass all `id's` for single change.

Answer (score 0):

i think  you need to store the "original state" like add a `rel` attribute at all your checkbox.
in this atribute you just write the `id` of an hidden field who store the original state of your checkbox.

```
<td class="cell"><input type="checkbox" id="shareRecorded" rel="shareRecordedState" /><span>Yes</span></td>
<input type="hidden" id="shareRecordedState" value="1"/>
```

Finally you just have to check the original state.